# Проверка содержимого QLineEdit после взаимодействия с другими объектами

Tags: python, ооп, qt-designer, qlineedit, pyside6

Мне нужно ввести число в поле `QLineEdit`, 
в моём случае это возраст человека (диапазон `от 18 до 80` лет).

После ввода и переключения фокуса на другой объект, например на другое поле или нажатия на кнопку, нужно чтобы программа проверяла, какое число введено, если оно меньше 18 или больше 80, вывести всплывающее окно с ошибкой и поставить фокус на это поле, если всё в порядке ничего не делать.

```
        from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
        QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
        QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
    from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
        QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
        QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
        QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget)
    
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            if not MainWindow.objectName():
                MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(371, 118)
            self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
            self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
            self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
            self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
            self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
            self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
            self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
    
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    
            self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")
    
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
    
    
            self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    
            self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout()
            self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
            self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
            self.label_2 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
    
            self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
    
            self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_2")
    
            self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
    
    
            self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    
            QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        # setupUi
    
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
            self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0412\u043e\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0442", None))
            self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0427\u0442\u043e-\u0442\u043e \u0434\u0440\u0443\u0433\u043e\u0435", None))
        # retranslateUi
        import sys
    from test import *
    
    class Test(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Test, self).__init__()
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Test()
        window.show()
    
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

Попытался сделать через `eventFilter`, всё получается, но есть проблема в фокусе. Если вернуть фокус, то курсора на нём не видно, так же хотелось бы сделать выделение всего текста, но `selectAll()` не работает.

```
    from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class QTApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QTApp, self).__init__()

        self.LE_sample_input_01 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.LE_sample_input_02 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.LE_sample_input_01)
        layout.addWidget(self.LE_sample_input_02)

        self.LE_sample_input_01.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut and QtGui.QFocusEvent.reason(event) == QtCore.Qt.MouseFocusReason:
            if obj is self.LE_sample_input_01:
                self.LE_sample_input_01.setFocus()
                try:
                    age = int(self.LE_sample_input_01.text())
                    if age < 18 or age > 80:
                        error = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
                        error.setWindowTitle('Ошибка возраста')
                        error.setText('Возраст введён неверно (от 18 до 80 лет)')
                        error.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
                        error.addButton('Ок',QtWidgets.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
                        error.exec()
                        obj.setFocus()
                        obj.selectAll()
                except:
                    print('Ошибка')
        return QtWidgets.QWidget.eventFilter(self,obj,event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    qt_app = QTApp()
    qt_app.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Devik, пожалуйста, покажите ваш код с попыткой что-то сделать.

Comment: и почему вы решили воспользоваться виджетом `QLineEdit` для ввода чисел?

Comment: Добавил архив с файлами кода

Comment: Devik, код должен быть в теле вопроса, не надо никаких ссылок.

Comment: Он не помещается :(

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Вроде как сделал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможный вариант решения, выглядит примерно так:

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
    QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget)
'''

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# ??? from test import *


# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):                                         # !!! +++

#!!! signal = Signal()                                         # !!! PySide6
    signal = pyqtSignal()                                      # !!! PyQt5

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        #print(f'focus In Event ')  
        self.setInputMask('00;#')
    
    def focusOutEvent(self, event):                                         # !!! +++
        #print(f'focus Out Event')  
        self.signal.emit()                                                  
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(371, 118)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(10)
        
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

#        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
# !!! +++
        self.lineEdit = LineEdit(self.centralwidget)                         # !!! +++
        
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(10)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)

        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0412\u043e\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0442", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0427\u0442\u043e-\u0442\u043e \u0434\u0440\u0443\u0433\u043e\u0435", None))
    

class Test(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.label.setMinimumWidth(120)
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(2)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.lineEdit.signal.connect(self.editing_finished)            # !!! +++
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.editing_finished)   # !!! +++

    def editing_finished(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        if not text:
            self.lineEdit.signal.disconnect(self.editing_finished)
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Заполните поле Возраст'
            )
            self.lineEdit.setFocus(True)
            self.lineEdit.signal.connect(self.editing_finished)
            return
            
        age = int(text) 
        if 18 <= age <= 80:
            self.lineEdit_2.setFocus(True)
        else:
            self.lineEdit.signal.disconnect(self.editing_finished)
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                f'Возраст (<b style="color: #f00;">{age}</b>) или меньше 18 или больше 80'
            )
            self.lineEdit.setFocus(True)
            self.lineEdit.signal.connect(self.editing_finished)
            return
            
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.lineEdit.signal.disconnect(self.editing_finished)
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.disconnect(self.editing_finished)
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    window = Test()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А с моим кодом который ниже, ничего нельзя сделать? (

Comment: @Devik я не смотрел ваш код, который ниже. Что не так в моем предложении?

Comment: Мне не нужна маска ввода

Comment: @Devik плохая практика обрабатывать исключения, если есть стандартные решения. Текст может быть произвольно ограничен с помощью `validator()` или `inputMask()`, или обоих.

Comment: А есть возможность убрать жирный курсор в маске?

Comment: @Devik это уже другой вопрос.