# Проверка после потери фокуса QLineEdit на Pyside6

Tags: python, qlineedit, pyside6

Нужно выполнить функцию, после того как `QLineEdit` потеряет фокус, \например нажатие на кнопку или выбор другого `QLineEdit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы зря удалили [**вопрос**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450920/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-qlineedit-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8#1450920), в котором более детально описали что вы собираетесь делать и привели пример вашего кода.

Так вот - вы не ответили, почему вы решили использовать виджет `QLineEdit`.
Я рекомендую вам для поля возраст использовать виджет `QSpinBox`.

Поменяйте импорты на свои (*PySide6*) и попробуйте.
У вас просто не получится набрать что-то отличное от `18 <= age <= 80`

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
    QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget)
'''

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# ??? from test import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(371, 118)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")

#        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)                    # !!! + 

        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")

        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_2")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 1)                  # !!! +
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0412\u043e\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0442", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0427\u0442\u043e-\u0442\u043e \u0434\u0440\u0443\u0433\u043e\u0435", None))
    

class Test(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.spinBox.setRange(18, 80)                                  # !!! +
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    window = Test()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Devik почему вы ничего не отвечаете? Если вам все же, по какой-то причине, хочется использовать виджет `QLineEdit`, то восстановите ваш удаленный вопрос и я вам в нем покажу как это может выглядеть.

Comment: Да, предложенный вами способ мне не подходит, я восстановил удалённый вопрос.

Comment: @Devik я думаю, что вы вернетесь именно к этому варианту спустя какое-то время, так как он очень даже подходит. Я дал ответ в восстановленном вами вопросе, проверьте.